# Javascript if condition showing always one value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript if condition code always gives same value. I want to display business if `res.display[i].type` is 1. and economy if `res.display[i].type` is 2.

```
$.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data)
            {
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(res.status == true)
                {

                    var results='';         

                    for(var i=0;  i<res.display.length;  i++) 
                    {    
                        console.log(res.display[i].type);  `
```

> this gives six 1 and three 2 but the if condition shows always 2.

```
                        if(res.display[i].type='1')
                        {   
                            var b="Business";
                        }
                        if(res.display[i].type='2')
                        {
                            var b="Economy";
                        }

                        results +='Seat ID:'+ res.display[i].seat_id +
                                  '<br>Seat:'+res.display[i].seat+
                                  '<br>Type:'+b+
```

> here the variable b is always 2. If i use `res.display[i].type` instead of the variable it displayed correctly. i.e six 1 and three 2 but instead of numbers i want to display business or economy.

```
                                  '<br><br>';
                        $('#result').html(results); 
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your equality operator is wrong, you are using `=` instead of `==`. Replace

```
if(res.display[i].type='1')
```

and

```
if(res.display[i].type='2')
```

with

```
if (res.display[i].type == '1')
```

and

```
if (res.display[i].type == '2')
```

The way you do it, `res.display[i].type` is assigned the value `'1'`, and that is the reason why it always enters that condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use comparison operator `==` for any type or `===` for same type,not `=` It assigns value, as you have written `res.display[i].type='1'` first, `res.display[i].type` value replaced by `1` and you are getting always `1`

```
 if(res.display[i].type=='1')
 {   
   var b="Business";
 }
 if(res.display[i].type=='2')
 {
   var b="Economy";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`'='` is an assignment operator, you should use `'=='` which checks the date the comparision operator,

```
if(res.display[i].type=='1')
    {   
    var b="Business";
    }
if(res.display[i].type=='2')
    {
    var b="Economy";
    }
```

**By using `=` you assign a value to something.**

```
x = 1 //x now equals 1
x = 2 //x now equals 2
```

**By using `==` you check if something is equal to something else. This is not strict**

```
x == 1 //is x equal to 1? (False)
x == 2 //is x equal to 2? (True)
true == 1 //does the boolean value of true equal 1? (True)
```

**By using `===` you check if something is equal to something else. This is also strict.**

```
x === 1 //is x equal to 1? (False)
x === 2 //is x equal to 2? (True)
true === 1 //does the boolean value of true equal 1? (False)
```